# Is there any limitation of character in messages or size in attachments of quickblox dialogs?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, quickblox

Is there any limitation on character size in the Quickblox messages? and Is there any limitation on size in the attachment (any format) while sending attachments in dialogs in Quickblox.

[Quickblox](https://quickblox.com/)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- limitation of character: no limits, but recommended to use no more than 1K characters
- size in the attachment: max 100 MB per file